# how to show string depending upon width of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have created two layout **vertically of equal width**. And I have string data to be displayed on text view dynamically. When string is greater than the width of the layout then string is wrapped to the width of the layout and for remaining string I want to create a new TV dynamically. This process ends till remaining string finishes. For next string same process  continues. When the process reaches bottom of linearlayout1, remaining string should starts from linearlayout2. And the process continues till it reaches bottom of linearlayout2.

I tried like this

```
private void nextlinechar(int numChars,String devstr) {
    nextchar=devstr;   
    Log.d("char 1",""+nextchar);
    TextView sub=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    sub.setLines(1);
    sub.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    sub.setTextSize(textsize);
    sub.setText(nextchar); 
    nextchar=devstr.substring(nextcharstart);
    String textToBeSplit = nextchar; // Text you want to split between TextViews
    String data=TextMeasure(nextchar,sub);
    float myTextSize=sub.getTextSize();
    float textView2Width=400;

 // String next=TextMeasure(nextchar,sub);
    Paint paint = new Paint();    
    paint.setTextSize(myTextSize); // Your text size
    numChars1= paint.breakText(textToBeSplit, true,textView2Width, null);
    nextchar1=nextchar.substring(numChars1);
 // Log.d("char",""+i+"  "+nextchar.length());
    main.addView(sub);   
    nextlinechar(numChars1,nextchar);
}
```

Illustration

[image]

Comment: Show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Its a very complex question to understand, a wall of text. Instead can you diagrammatically illustrate what you need, and what you are seeing now ?

Comment: @Siddharth hey please see my edited question uploaded image.I want this kind of layout.Can you please help me to find solution

Comment: if/when you find a solution please post it or a link or whatever :)

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Solution 1**

What you need is a FlowLayout, found [here](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout). Basically the text needs to wrap around, instead of overflow to the right.

**Possible Solution 2**

Try to use a webview instead, and populate the text in 2 webviews. That will be faster with lesser code and not as buggy.

I used FlowLayout only when I needed to click on each word separately. Basically a test for grammar where people select the Parts Of Speech of the sentence. For that I needed listener on each word.

Comment: hey i also want to add images in b/w text then what to do?

Comment: Solution 2 is best, that way you can play around with your content a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Reffer This may be this help you:

```
 package com.example.demo;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FontFitTextView extends TextView {

        public FontFitTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            initialise();
        }

        public FontFitTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            initialise();
        }

        private void initialise() {
            mTestPaint = new Paint();
            mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());
            // max size defaults to the initially specified text size unless it is
            // too small
        }

        /*
         * Re size the font so the specified text fits in the text box assuming the
         * text box is the specified width.
         */
        private void refitText(String text, int textWidth) {
            if (textWidth <= 0)
                return;
            int targetWidth = textWidth - this.getPaddingLeft()
                    - this.getPaddingRight();
            float hi = 100;
            float lo = 2;
            final float threshold = 0.5f; // How close we have to be

            mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());

            while ((hi - lo) > threshold) {
                float size = (hi + lo) / 2;
                mTestPaint.setTextSize(size);
                if (mTestPaint.measureText(text) >= targetWidth)
                    hi = size; // too big
                else
                    lo = size; // too small
            }
            // Use lo so that we undershoot rather than overshoot
            this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lo);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = getMeasuredHeight();
            refitText(this.getText().toString(), parentWidth);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
                final int before, final int after) {
            refitText(text.toString(), this.getWidth());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            if (w != oldw) {
                refitText(this.getText().toString(), w);
            }
        }

        // Attributes
        private Paint mTestPaint;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an idea I came up with (of course I first tried to search for a built-in method of TextViwe which does what you need, but couldn't find any):

1. Determine how many lines should be displayed in each of the layouts (left and right) depending on the screen size (this.getResources().getDefaultDisplay() and then search for the right method), the desired text size and the spaces between the layouts and between the text and the top/bottom edges. Don't forget you may need to convert pixels to dips or vice versa, as most Android size measure methods return size in pixels.
2. Set the max number of lines to each of the TVs (tv.setLines()).
3. Set the entire text to the left TV.
4. Now the first half of the text will be displayed in the left TV. The other part of the text will be hidden because you've reached the max num of lines in the TV. So, use getText() to receive the text currently displayed in the TV (hopefully, this will return only the first half of the text.. haven't tried that out yet, sorry. If not, maybe there's some getDisplayedText() method or something). Now you can use simple Java methods to retrieve only the remining part of the text from the original text (a substring) and set it to the second TV.

Hope that helps.